# rake:db migrate not happening in Refinery CMS app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, refinerycms

Doing the tutorial on using the Refinery CMS at http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started#rails-application-templates and at the point of

**6 Extending Refinery with your first Engine**

which says to run

```
rails generate refinery:engine singular_model_name attribute:type [attribute:type ...]
```

then to run

```
rails generate refinery:engine event title:string date:datetime photo:image blurb:text
```

Afterwards I went through the rest but `rake db:migrate` did not seem to work because when I tried to run `rake db:seed` I got an  error that I needed to run `rake db:migrate` . I tried running the app locally and got this

[image: events]

This was in the terminal somewhere and looks relevant

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find table 'refinery_events'):
1: <%= render 'refinery/admin/search_header', :url => refinery.events_admin_events_path %>
2: <div class='pagination_container'>
3:   <% if @events.any? %>
4:     <%= render 'events' %>
5:   <% else %>
6:     <p>
```

I also got this error about authors, but the tutorial had not mentioned it

```
Using refinerycms-events (1.0) from source at vendor/extensions
refinerycms-events at /Users/juan.gallardo/Desktop/myfiles/test-projects/rickrockstar/vendor/extensions/events did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  authors may not be empty

Using refinerycms-singular_model_names (1.0) from source at vendor/extensions
refinerycms-singular_model_names at /Users/juan.gallardo/Desktop/myfiles/test-projects/rickrockstar/vendor/extensions/singular_model_names did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  authors may not be empty
```

So I went through the process again

```
jgallardo:rickrockstar juan.gallardo$ rails generate refinery:events
    rake  refinery_events:install:migrations
  append  db/seeds.rb
jgallardo:rickrockstar juan.gallardo$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
```

This time I clearly saw the `rake aborted` but tried this anyways

```
jgallardo:rickrockstar juan.gallardo$ rake db:seed
You have 2 pending migrations:
  20130826173639 CreateSingularModelNamesSingularModelNames
  20130826173941 CreateEventsEvents
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

I searched on Google about what pending migrations meant, and I saw that someone told someone else with a similar problem to run with `--trace` so here was my attempt

```
jgallardo:rickrockstar juan.gallardo$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
/Users/juan.gallardo/Desktop/myfiles/test-projects/rickrockstar/db/migrate/20130826173639_create_singular_model_names_singular_model_names.refinery_singular_model_names.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
  t.type :[attribute
           ^
/Users/juan.gallardo/Desktop/myfiles/test-projects/rickrockstar/db/migrate/20130826173639_create_singular_model_names_singular_model_names.refinery_singular_model_names.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ..., expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
  t.string :...]
               ^
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:537:in `load_migration'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:533:in `migration'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/juan.gallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: If you are running refinery as an engine, you will have to run migrations from inside test/dummy or spec/dummy directory.

Comment: This is an example, you aren't meant to type this word for word:

    rails generate refinery:engine singular_model_name attribute:type [attribute:type ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorials work best if you read and think about what they are saying rather than just copying & pasting parts of them into your Terminal.

In this case, the example you copied and pasted was:

```
rails generate refinery:engine singular_model_name attribute:type [attribute:type ...]
```

You successfully substituted this for correct syntax when you generated the events extension, though, so no problem with that one.

Delete the migration titled CreateSingularModelNamesSingularModelNames and its entire corresponding extension. You copy pasted example syntax which doesn't result in valid Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understand your point about taking the time to think through the documentation, and I am extremely grateful of the excellent documentation that you have and the time you take to address questions. It is, however, nice to be able to copy paste at least the very first project while we learn. Maybe that code can be marked differently though.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the accepted answer, I copy pasted the wrong code as show below under 6.2

[image: sample code]

I ended up just deleting the project and starting over. But then I copy pasted from below

[image: copy pasta]

Everything worked fine after.